# How to Determine the Top Medical Science Professors in Specific Fields?

Tags: obstetrics

If I want to determine the top medical science professors in a specific field and contact them, how would I go about doing so?  I especially want to contact clinical professors.  Currently, I am looking for contacts in obstetrics but I will have the need to contact clinical professors in other fields.

Any guidance and advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: As pointed out in the answer by @cherenkov, this is an opinion-based question because evaluation of 'top' anything or anyone is subjective to a point. You can have all the qualifications in the subject but be terrible compared to another who has the minimum qualifications required whether through ability or through ethics etc.

Comment: Chris, you are twisting the meaning of opinion so that you can invalidate this question.  Look at all the other questions.  There are always some sort of opinion that is given in an answer.  This is axiomatic.

Comment: Bryan, I want to contact them because I would like to discuss certain topics with them.  I'd like to go to top clinical professors instead of wasting my time.

Comment: Chris, if you really think "top" is subjective, then you aren't really thinking clearly.  I can name the top professors in my field.  I can name you the top 5 right away.  There isn't any vague or confusing with the term "top".  It's like saying who is the best basketball players right now.  You can say Lebron, Curry, etc.  You are making an easy question into a hard one.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it mostly depends on what you mean by "**Top Professor**". In my opinion, there's no thing as "Top". There's the most influents on the scientific community (e.g. in my field, if [Milton Packer](https://scholar.google.com/citations?user=HXRv1ZAAAAAJ&hl=en) says something about Heart failure, you're more prone to trust him because of his resumé), there's the good teachers, the ones with outstanding human qualities et cetera.

Here's some hints:

If you're looking for the ones that have the most impact on the scientific community, you could go and search the topic you're interested in (e.g. "Placenta Previa") on google scholar and then look at the authors of the most cited articles (this method is far from being perfect because citations can be [biased in many ways](https://handbook-5-1.cochrane.org/chapter_10/10_2_2_3_citation_bias.htm)).

One other thing you could do is searching for guidelines on the topic you're interested in and looking at who wrote them. For example, these are [ESC Guidelines on Cardiovascular disease during pregnancy](https://www.escardio.org/Guidelines/Clinical-Practice-Guidelines/Cardiovascular-Diseases-during-Pregnancy-Management-of).

Then, if you're curious about who gives the "best" lectures (better: the ones you like the most), you can search on google for congresses where they were invited and give a look at their lectures.

I tried to give you some directions but bear in mind that every method is not perfect and there most certainly are very good professors, super skilled at teaching, that are just average researchers and not incredibly influent.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115817/discussion-on-answer-by-cherenkov-how-to-determine-the-top-medical-science-profe).